# M2M django with more attributes

Tags: django, django-models, m2m

Im a bit confused about a M2M with django, I have the following issue:

Each user can has too many skills and per skill the user have to choose the time of experience. I mean, django-1 year, Heroku-3 years, and like this so on, how can I implement that in django?

My models:

```
class Specialities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Experience(models.Model):
    specialities = models.ManyToManyField('self',through='RegisterProfessional',symmetrical = False)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.years

class RegisterProfessional(models.Model):
    id_document = models.OneToOneField(User)
    specialities = models.ForeignKey(Specialities)
    anios = models.ForeignKey(Experience)
```

How can I fix my model to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to make it as simple as possible:

```
class Speciality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class User(models.Model):
    specialities = models.ManyToManyField('self',through='RegisterProfessional',symmetrical = False)


class RegisterProfessional(models.Model):
    id_document = models.ForeignKey(User)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ('id_document', 'speciality')
```

And for user, if you mean the django authentication user, [there is a way to extend it easily](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) to be able to add specialities direct to the `User` model.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Here is where Im confused, why FK in speciality in RegisterProfessional? How can I add more than one speciality in RegisterProfessional?... In the admin of User model does not appear any field.

Comment: It must be a FK, RegisterProfessional is the join table which make the m2m relation between `User` and `Speciality`. On the admin you must use `TabularInline` as mentioned on the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models and you will be able to add many specialities to a user.